# Does my sklearn pipeline also scale my dependent variables y?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

My confusion is about pipeline. Suppose my code is

```
pipe=Pipeline([('sc',StandardScaler()),
               ('pca',PCA(n_components=2)),
               ('lr',LinearRegression())])
```

and i called `pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)`. Does this also scale the `y_train` values?

Comment: No. Never. `y_train` will be only used id needed for the steps in the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. If pipeline scaled labels too, you would get scaled predictions as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. 
`Pipeline` sequentially applies the `fit` method and then the `transform` method to each of the steps, except for the last one, which only needs the `fit` method. Your first two classes in the pipeline are `StandardScaler` and `PCA`, and both of them apply the `fit` method ignoring the `y_train` values, therefore, they only depend on the `X_train` data. For the final step, `LinearRegression` will receive the transformed `X_train` values, and will call the `fit` method with them, but also with the original `y_train` values.